# Demonized Celery for django project

Tags: python, django, rabbitmq, celery

I have already wasted a lot of time figuring out how to execute task in django project with demonized celery

VERSIONS
    django version is 1.3
    celery version is 3.1

my directory structure is

```
project/
   ./manage.py
   ./settings.py

   ./celeryapp/
       ./celeryqueue.py
       ./tasks.py
```

i have been able to run celery in demonized mode by creating "/etc/init.d/celeryd" as specified at [here](http://ask.github.io/celery/cookbook/daemonizing.html#generic-init-scripts)

also copied config file for demonized celery specified at [here](http://ask.github.io/celery/cookbook/daemonizing.html#example-configuration)

```
# Name of nodes to start
# here we have a single node
CELERYD_NODES="w1"
# or we could have three nodes:
#CELERYD_NODES="w1 w2 w3"

# Where to chdir at start.
CELERYD_CHDIR="/opt/project/"

# Extra arguments to celeryd
CELERYD_OPTS="--time-limit=300 --concurrency=8"

# Name of the celery config module.
CELERY_CONFIG_MODULE="celeryconfig"

# %n will be replaced with the nodename.
CELERYD_LOG_FILE="/var/log/celery/%n.log"
CELERYD_PID_FILE="/var/run/celery/%n.pid"

# Workers should run as an unprivileged user.
CELERYD_USER="celery"
CELERYD_GROUP="celery"
```

My celeryconfig.py is

```
BROKER_URL = 'amqp://'

CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = 'amqp://'

CELERY_IMPORTS = ("celeryapp.tasks",)
```

I have created celery user and given required privileges by executing

```
rabbitmqctl add_user celery celery  
rabbitmqctl add_vhost celeryvhost  
rabbitmqctl set_permissions -p celeryvhost celery ".*" ".*"
```

Still i am getting KeyError saying

```
Received unregistered task of type "mytaskname"
```

This is the traceback

```
ERROR/MainProcess] Received unregistered task of type 'process_transcoding'.  
The message has been ignored and discarded.  
Did you remember to import the module containing this task?  
Or maybe you are using relative imports?  
Please see http://bit.ly/gLye1c for more information.  
The full contents of the message body was:  
{'utc': True, 'chord': None, 'args': [2202L,u'/opt/ossite/media/videos/Screenshot_from_2013-09-24_150354_1.png', u'/opt/ossite/media/thumbnails/Screenshot_from_2013-09-24_150354_1.jpeg', 'thumbnail'], 'retries': 0, 'expires': None, 'task': 'process_transcoding', 'callbacks': None, 'errbacks': None, 'timelimit': (None, None), 'taskset': None, 'kwargs': {}, 'eta': None, 'id': 'f8468f52-ade3-4405-96d6-21a187583c77'} (381b)  
Traceback (most recent call last):  
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/celery/worker/consumer.py", line 457, in  on_task_received  
strategies[name](message, body,
KeyError: 'process_transcoding'
```

Desperately waiting for help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How do you import and add tasks to a queue? Do you use relative imports? `from celeryapp.tasks import mytaskname` and `mytaskname.delay()` should work.

Comment: Yes i am doing it the same way, but its not working with daemon.

Comment: @daniula: Actually i was doing that way, but somehow i move my tasks to class.  
so Now i am importing class like  
    
    from celeryapp.tasks import CeleryTasks  

    and calling task by creating object like  

    ctask = CeleryTasks()  
    ctask.mytaskname.apply_async(args)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally My boss got the bandwidth to sit with me, and he found the exact problem.

And the problem was relative imports...

I just needed to append "project." for every project related import for all the imports in tasks.py and in all the imports in imported files too. 
e.g

```
tasks.py  
from celeryapp.celeryqueue import app # replaced by  
from project.celeryapp.celeryqueue import app  # and  

from abc import xyz  # is replced by  
from project.abc import xyz  

xyz.py  
from pqr import stu # is replced by
from project.pqr import stu
```

and so on...

Here is the link as daniula suggested [relative imports](http://celery.readthedocs.org/en/latest/userguide/tasks.html#automatic-naming-and-relative-imports)

Comment: Add this link to your answer and set it as accepted so people who find your question, will know how you solved it. http://celery.readthedocs.org/en/latest/userguide/tasks.html#automatic-naming-and-relative-imports

Comment: exactly. Thanks Daniula :-)

Answer (score 0):

Can you add "--loglevel=DEBUG" to configs:

```
# Extra arguments to celeryd
CELERYD_OPTS="--time-limit=300 --concurrency=8 --loglevel=DEBUG"
```

Check the log files and edit your question with whatever unusual you see there.
The problem you described can be due to many reasons.

Comment: CELERY_IMPORTS = ("celeryapp.tasks",) might be the problem. Can you also check if your celeryconfig.py is in the pythonpath. If not, then add it and try again.

Comment: yes celeryconfig.py is at same level as settings.py

Comment: Its getting harder to guess. Just for experimentation, can you use settings.py only for celery configs instead of a separate celeryconfig.py  . Also if possible, do add some lines from your log files in your question description.

Comment: also try giving "--settings=celeryconfig.py" as an argument while running. Are you using python manage.py celeryd to run the daemon or /etc/init.d/celeryd start?

Comment: Yeah I tried using settings.py for conf. it works with python manage.py celeryd. also if i add "-lDEBUG" manage.py command it shows all my task and works fine. But for production server i want celery to run in daemon mode.

also i m editing my question to add error trace in logfile.